# Finding the differences between two files

Tags: bash, file, shell, scripting

I have a couple of packages lists, with hundreds of entries, and I would like to find the differences of them.

The contents of the files look like

File 1:

```
somepackage1 0.1
somepackage2 5.6
somepackage3 1.3-1
etc...
```

File 2:

```
somepackage1 0.1
somepackage2 5.7
somepackage3 1.3-1
somepackage4 0.1
etc...
```

I'm looking for a couple of commands or a script that can produce all the new packages that were added. Not just the version numbers, but if a new package was added.

So, for example the command or script would output `somepackage4` given the above two files.

I've been playing with some commands, but can't get any of them work properly. Does anyone have a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to compare the first column in the files and print the lines that are unique in the second one.  Use `comm`:

```
comm -13 <(awk '{print $1}' file1 | sort) <(awk '{print $1}' file2 | sort)
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
somepackage4
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I wanted!. I was playing around with diff, but since they weren't always on the same line numbers, that just wasn't working work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `grep`
to find packages in listed in file2 but not in file1

```
grep -vf <(cut -d' ' -f1 file1)  <(cut -d' ' -f1 file2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $1}' file1 file2
```